# Angular2: Enhance the performance of scroll event with a big ngFor List

Tags: javascript, performance, angular, infinite-scroll, ngfor

I'm developing a web chat, the structute of the chat shows the messages like this:

```
<div class="scrollable" (scroll)="detectTop($event)">
    <div class="message-ballon" *ngfor="message in messages">
        <span class="time-chat" *ngIf="showTime(message)"> {{message.time}} </span>
        <p class="message-content"> {{message.content}} </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

My detectTop(e) function checks if scrollTop === 0 if yes it get more messages from server and updates messages with it.

My showTime function compares the message with the messages above it to check if it is the same date.

The problem is the app is painfully slow, without the scroll event the scrolls works ok and is very fast.

I really want to increase the performance, but I'm not figuring how.

There is a faster way to detect scrollTop event and not impact so much on performance?

This problem is big even with small 10 messages list, and with more than 100 messsages the scroll stops

Comment: do you have a plnkr demonstrating this?

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers?

Comment: On Firefox it works much faster than on Chrome

Comment: I forgot to include the ngIf part of showTime, this is what was slowing the app. I changing it to *ngIf="message.showTime" and is working now. Thank you guys

Answer (score 3):

try adding a tracker to the *ngFor loop:

```
*ngFor="let message of messages; trackBy:messageTracker
```

and in your JS code:

```
messageTracker(index, message) {
  return message? message.id : undefined;
}
```

this will avoid re-rendering the messages on scroll